# find smallest whole number missing form bitwise OR of all the subsequence of given array?

Tags: arrays, bitwise-operators, subsequence, bitwise-or

as the question suggests we need to find **OR** of all the subsequence of given array

```
`arr = { 1,3,4,0} `
bitwise OR of all subsequence
`[0] =>  0
[4]  => 4
[4, 0] => 4
[3]  => 3
[3, 0] => 3
[3, 4] => 7
[3, 4, 0] => 7
[1] => 1
[1, 0] => 1
[1, 4] => 5
[1, 4, 0] => 5
[1, 3] => 3
[1, 3, 0] => 3
[1, 3, 4] => 7
[1, 3, 4, 0] => 7`

so bitwise OR of all the subsequence is 
`{0,1,3,4,5,7}`
exclude repeated, **smallest missing whole** no is 2


now `1<= array.length <= 10^5 and 0<= arr[i] <= 10^5`
```

how do you solve this with an optimized approach, not exponential complexity (without generating all the subsequnce)?

Answer (score 0):

The logic is simple.

- step-1. Find All possible subSequences and calculate a bitwise on each subSequence we found and then store values in list(bitwRes).
- step-2. Sort the list(bitwRes).
- step-3. take the first value+1 from List(bitwRes) and check whether available or not in the list(bitwRes) if there increment by 1.
  -step-3 executes until we didn't find the value **smallest missing whole number**.

`

```
    public int findSmalestWholeNumber(List<Integer> list){

      List<Integer> bitwRes = new ArrayList<Integer>();     
      subSeq(0, list, new ArrayList<Integer>(), bitwRes);
      Collections.sort(bitwRes);
            
      int j = bitwRes.get(0);
      for(int i=1; i<bitwRes.size(); i++)
      {
        if(bitwRes.contains(j++))
            continue;
        else {
            return --j;     
            break;
        }               
    }
    return 0;
    }

    public static void subSeq(int i, List<Integer> list, List<Integer> ds, List<Integer> bitwRes){

      if(i>=list.size())
      {
        // Doing-Biwise OR operations 
         int add = 0;
         for(int j: ds) {
            add |= j;
        }
        bitwRes.add(add);
        return;
       }
    
       ds.add(list.get(i));
       subSeq(i+1, list, ds, bitwRes);
       ds.remove(list.get(i));
       subSeq(i+1, list, ds, bitwRes);
      }
    }
```

'
#Java #StriverYoutube(Learned bit about Recursions by using your videosThanks)

Comment: hi thanks for the answer , but it's not the optimized solution, if you take to look at complexity it would be 2^n  ( n= length of arr) , I mentioned this in the question complexity must not be exponential.